# 'Selecting by freehand' tool - selection disappears

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, domains

I have been trying to select some features of my map on QGIS to create the boundaries of a domain, however when I draw a shape using the 'Select by freehand' tool, the selection disappears as soon as I release the mouse.

Basically, I can only see the selection while I click and drag across the map, but I am unable to save what I have selected.

Can somebody help me figure out why?

Comment: do you mean you already have some features selected then when you try to select more the previous selection disappears? If so, hold down CTRL while you're making another selection (as you would if you were selecting multiple files on your computer)

Comment: When you select your features, is it highlighted in the _Attribute Table_? Also @DPSSpatial, my QGIS uses SHIFT to make multiple selections ;)

Comment: @Joseph really? Weird... my QGIS 2.14 on Linux Mint and Windows uses CTRL...

Comment: @DPSSpatial - I'm sure I changed a setting somewhere at some point because I did use CTRL before (I use Windows).

Comment: @Joseph ah! gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you do not have the layer you are trying to select from highlighted. There would be no points from the highlighted layer to select so it selects nothing.